# Finding a character variable in a column

Tags: r

I have a huge data frame df, with many columns. One of the columns named `id_nm` happens to be a character with values such as: `aksh123dn.Ins`

```
class(df$id_nm)
```

returns `character`

I need to lookup all those values which have the `id_nm` say `aksh123dn.Ins`
I used:

```
new_df<-df[df$id_nm=='aksh123dn.Ins',]
```

this returns the entire df which isn't the case in reality

also tried:

```
new_df<-df%filter(id_nm=='aksh123dn.Ins']
```

still getting the same answer

I think its possibly because it is a character string. Please help me with this. TIA

Comment: You need `df$id_nm[df$id_nm=='aksh123dn.Ins']` The column index (after the `,`) is not given.  So it returns the full data columns or either `df[df$id_nm=='aksh123dn.Ins', "id_nm"]`. But, I prefer the first option as it may be more efficient.  Same issue in `filter`.  `filter` filters the rows and not column.  You need `%>% pull(id_nm)` after that to extract as a vector

Comment: @akrun but that would yield only the id_nm column with matching values, I want the other columns present as well

Comment: What is the issue in your code `df[df$id_nm=='aksh123dn.Ins',]` it returns all the columns as I underestand.  Your description says `this returns the entire df which isn't the case in reality` and the comment here is kind of confusing.  If your question is about not finding the rows, then it would be an issue with leading/lagging spaces i.e. try with `trimws` `df[trimws(df$id_nm)=='aksh123dn.Ins',]`

Comment: This seems odd. `df[df$id_nm=='aksh123dn.Ins',]` looks right to me, as in you're selecting all the rows that meet the condition you want.  Maybe all rows meet that condition? You can inspect that by using `print(unique(df$id_nm))`  and check what other possible values are in that column.